# Reference for "almost all graphs have diameter 2"

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

The property in the title is well-known. I am trying to find an original reference to its first appearance in print. The 4th edition of *Graphs & Digraphs* by Chartrand and Lesniak lists this as Theorem 13.6 and says that it's a generalization of a result by Gilbert, but gives no further reference.

Answer (score 5):

I think you will find it in Moon, J. W.; Moser, L.
Almost all (0,1) matrices are primitive. 
Studia Sci. Math. Hungar. 1 (1966) 153–156.
But I don't have time to visit the library to be sure and I don't see it online.

It is certainly in 
Burtin, Ju. D.
Asymptotic estimates of the diameter and the independence and domination numbers of a random graph. (Russian) 
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 209 (1973), 765–768.

I guess the Gilbert mentioned is Gilbert, E. N.
Random graphs. 
Ann. Math. Statist. 30 (1959) 1141–1144.  It isn't clear exactly why...

Comment: The introductory paragraph of a 1981 *TAMS* paper by Bollobas available at http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1981-267-01/S0002-9947-1981-0621971-7/S0002-9947-1981-0621971-7.pdf supports the likely Moon-Moser origin.  Also, an author search on "e.n. gilbert" at http://projecteuclid.org/ will produce his "Random Graphs" article.

Comment: I checked the Moon Moser paper, that is indeed your reference. I've emailed you a somewhat crappy but legible scan of the paper. 

Answer (score 4):

The result you asked about follows instantly from Fagin's proof of the zero-one law for finite graphs.  He shows that all of Gaifman's extension axioms have asymptotic probability 1, and "diameter $\leq 2$" is essentially one of the extension axioms.  Fagin's paper is "Probabilities on finite models" [J. Symbolic Logic 41 (1976) pp.50-58].  I believe the zero-one law was proved earlier by four Russians, but I don't have access to their paper and don't know whether their method immediately implies the "diameter $\leq2$" result.

Comment: The four Russians are Y.V. Glebskii, D.I. Kogan, M.I. Liogon'kii, and V.A. Talanov.  The paper is "Range and degree of realizability of formulas in the restricted predicate calculus" [Kibernetika (Kiev) 1969, no.2, 17-28; translation in Cybenetics (Kiev) 5 (1969) 142-154].  I've been told that this paper is rather difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks! I actually know this derivation, but I wanted a encapsulated reference to this precise fact.